# position of the current view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to get the top coordinate(position) of the windows view. For instance if I want to know the position of an element i.e button I can use `var x = $("#btn").position()` and get the top value by `alert(x.top)`. what I want to know is how to get the top position of the current view.

```html
<image src="https://www.setaswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Beautiful-Wallpaper-1080x2160.jpg"></image>
```

In above page, lets say the user has scrolled down to the middle page. How can i know that the user view is on the middle of the page rather than bottom of the page or top of the page interms of position.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but aren't you looking for `document.documentElement.scrollTop` ??

Comment: can you find out if the user is viewing the most top image or in the middle image with that? to be more specific, if the user is viewing the top page then 'document.documentElement.scrollTop' should return 0 if it's at the middle then 'document.documentElement.scrollTop' should return half the page size

Comment: yes, that's what it is for

Comment: you can respond a code as an answer nd i will upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the position of the viewport with respect to topmost part of the document:

```
var pos = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.parentElement.scrollTop;
```

To get the total "length" (scrollable height) of your document:

```
var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight || document.body.parentElement.scrollHeight;
```

To get an idea of which section the user is looking at:

```
var ratio = pos/height;
```

if the above ratio is close to 0.5, then you are looking at the "middle" etc..You can elaborate..

Comment: exactly what i am looking for

Comment: Do not forget that the ratio is respect to the "top" of the viewport, that is the top edge of your monitor. To get with respect to the middle of your monitor, add to `pos`, half the clientHeight and that is `(document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.parentElement.clientHeight;)/2`